# Time dilation from the Equivalence Principle

Tags: general-relativity, time-dilation, equivalence-principle

I've read as many questions as I can before asking this question, but most questions involve examples of specific situations with specific spacetime metrics, which is helpful but not really what I'm looking for. I'm trying to understand how, if possible, gravitational time dilation can be directly begotten from the equivalence principle. I can understand how we might arrive at the conclusion that time is dilated indirectly, by reference to the gravitational red-shift. What I'm looking for is a direct method to arrive at time dilation from the equivalence principle without an intermediate step.
I read [this paper](http://www.relativitycalculator.com/pdfs/Einstein_1907_the_relativity_principle.pdf) which seems to do just what I'm looking for but I got confused when it talked about different clocks in different reference frames being synchronous to each other.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don’t understand this distinction you are trying to draw between gravitational redshift and gravitational time dilation. Nor direct vs indirect.

Comment: @Dale here's what I'm getting at. You can apply the equivalence principle to examine a light beam moving along the direction of a gravitational field. From that examination you arrive at the conclusion that light is red-shifted the farther away it is from the gravitational source. In other words, its frequency drops. You then interpret that to be an effect of gravity on the rate at which time itself passes in a gravitational field. Here we used an intermediate step (gravity's effect on light) to arrive at gravity's effect on time. And what I'm seeking is an explanation without such a step.

Comment: From the viewpoint of an accelerated observer, a stone without motion in an inertial frame seems to gain velocity. Relative to the accelerated observer the stone will gain motion through space which must be accompanied with smaller velocity through time. So the clocks in the accelerated frame will tick differently in the direction of acceleration.

Comment: @user626452 I don’t think you can avoid the metric then. You have contradictory requirements. If you don’t want to use the metric, which deals directly with time, then you will need to use some sort of experiment which will be an indirect indication of time.

Answer (score 0):

The Rindler's concept of an accelerated reference frame is a good example to link the principle of equivalence to gravitation in my opinion. It is a reference frame in the meaning that each point $X$ keeps always the same distance from the others.

But contrary to an inertial frame, the clocks can not be synchronized for observers at different locations.

It is not necessary to derive the metric for this spacetime to get this conclusions. From the graphs of the hyperbolas in a t-x inertial frame, it is possible to see that there is an initial situation of synchronization, (the x-axis), where the accelerated  frame is momentarily at rest. The green line intercepts the curves, and the interception points have the same velocity (tangent to the curves), keeping that way the relative distance constant.

But clearly the times are different now for each point of the accelerated frame.

[image]